# how to fix an 'invalid value encountered in power' error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a function to evaluate and return a non linear system of equations, and give the jacobian. I then plan to call the function in a `while` loop to use the newton method to solve the system of equations.

I used the numpy package and read over its documentation, tried to limit the number of iterations, changed the `dtype` in the array and searched online to see if someone else had a similar problem.

This function is meant to solve a neoclassical growth model (a problem in macroeconomics) in finite time , T. The set of equations include T euler equations, T constraints, and one terminal condition. Thus the result should be an array of length 2T+1 containing the values of the equations, and a (2T+1)x(2T+1) jacobian matrix.

When I try to run the function for small array (arrays of length 1, and 3) it works perfectly. As soon as I try an array of length 5 or more, I start encountering RuntimeWarnings.

```
import numpy as np
def solver(args, params):
    b,s,a,d = params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]
    guess = np.copy(args)

    #Euler
    euler = guess[:len(guess)//2]**(-sigma) - beta*guess[1:len(guess)//2+1]**(-sigma)*(1-delta+alpha*guess[len(guess)//2+1:]**(alpha-1))

    #Budget Constraint
    kzero_to_T = np.concatenate(([k0], guess[len(guess)//2+1:]))
    bc_t = guess[:len(guess)//2] + guess[len(guess)//2+1:] - kzero_to_T[:-1]**alpha - (1-delta)*kzero_to_T[:-1]
    bc_f = guess[len(guess)//2] -kzero_to_T[-1]**alpha - kzero_to_T[-1]*(1-delta)
    bc = np.hstack((bc_t, bc_f))
    Evals = np.concatenate((euler, bc))

    # top half of the jacobian
    jac_dot_5 = np.zeros((len(args)//2, len(args)))
    for t in range(len(args)//2):
        for i in range(len(args)):
            if t == i and len(args)//2+(i+1)<=len(args):
                jac_dot_5[t][t] = -sigma*args[t]**(-sigma-1)
                jac_dot_5[t][t+1] = sigma*beta*args[t+1]*(1-delta+alpha*args[len(args)//2+(t+1)]**(alpha-1))
                jac_dot_5[t][len(args)//2+(t+1)] = beta*args[t+1]**(-sigma)*alpha*(alpha-1)*args[len(args)//2+(t+1)]

    # bottom half of the jacobian   
    jac_dot_1 = np.zeros((len(args)//2, len(args)))

    for u in range(len(args)//2):
        for v in range(len(args)):
            if u==v and u>=1 and (len(args)//2 + u+1 < len(args)):
                jac_dot_1[u][u] =  1
                jac_dot_1[u][len(args)//2+(u)] = 1
                jac_dot_1[u][len(args)//2+(u+1)] = -alpha*args[len(args)//2 + (u+1)]**(alpha-1) -(1-delta)
    jac_dot_1[0][0] = 1
    jac_dot_1[0][len(args)//2 +1] = 1

    # last row of the jacobian
    final_bc = np.zeros((1,len(args)))
    final_bc[0][len(args)//2] = 1
    final_bc[0][-1] = -alpha*args[-1]**(alpha-1) -(1-delta)

    jac2Tn1 = np.concatenate((jac_dot_5, jac_dot_1, final_bc), axis=0) 

    point = coll.namedtuple('point', ['Output', 'Jacobian', 'Euler', 'BC'])
    result = point(Output = Evals, Jacobian = jac2Tn1, Euler=euler, BC=bc )

    return result
```

The code for implementing the algorithm:

```
p = (beta, sigma, alpha, delta)
for i in range(20):
    k0 = np.linspace(2.49, 9.96, 20)[i]
    vars0 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=float)
    vars1 = np.array([20,20,20,20,20], dtype=float)
    Iter2= 0

    while abs(solver(vars1,p).Output).max()>1e-8 and Iter2<300:
        Iter2+=1
        inv_jac1 = np.linalg.inv(solver(vars0,p).Jacobian)
        vars1 = vars0 - inv_jac1@solver(vars0,p).Output
        vars0=vars1
        if Iter2 == 100:
            break
```

I expect the output to be `vars1` containing the updated values. The actual output is `array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])`. The way the function has been written, it should be able to give the output for inputs of arbitrary guesses of length 2T+1, where T is number of periods of time.

I get three error messages during the execution of the loop:

```
C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:23: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:41: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

I tried to code my issue from scratch and I couldn't make it any shorter- I need both, the evaluations of the equations and the jacobian to implement the algorithm. From my testing it looks like at some point the equation results (the `solver(vars0,p).Output` entry) become `nan,` but I am not sure why that would happen, the array should get close to 0, per the condition `abs(solver(vars1,p).Output).max()>1e-8` and then just break out of the loop.

Comment: `invalid value encountered in power` is produced when the base array has a negative value, and the power is not a positive integer (negative or float), e.g. `np.array([-100.0])**2.3 `

Comment: I had included a line using `numpy.where` to ensure all negative values would be converted to zero, as entries less than 0 cannot be a part of the valid solution space, but it made no difference, so I ended up taking it out.